# Python dependencies in ruby on rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, web

Today I bring you a true newbie question. I have made a couple cool python scripts utilizing (among others) `numpy`, `scipy` and `pygame`. Now I thought it would be cool to put everything on a webpage through `Ruby on Rails`. Is... is this possible? Does it even make sense? I know on a basic level how webpages work, but how would things like a python dependency come into play in this context?

Sorry if the question does not make much sense

Comment: You could use python to put it on the web. http://flask.pocoo.org/ is really simple to use.  https://www.djangoproject.com/ is more complex but more powerful.

Comment: @SimonFraser thank you for responding I will check those out